# phoneGap and android version. Issue with CSS3 Flex

Tags: css, cordova, flexbox

I am developing an app with phoneGap that will be used in Android Systems (and only with Android).

Today I generated the .apk file and tried it in my Galaxy S4, all is visualized perfect.
I developed it using chrome and the chrome developer console, of course reaching the same perfect visualization.
I tried the app also on a "Huawei G620-L01" with Android version 4.4.4 with no problems at all, on a OnePlus One with Android 5.0.2 with no problems at all.

Then I tried to install it on a Acer Iconia B1 Tablet with Android 4.1.2 and everywhere I used the attribute:

```
.class{
    display:flex;
}
```

of CSS3 I've got big errors in visualizations.

It seem to me that there is a problem with old android versions not recognizing CSS3, but I am lost in finding a solution because everything *should* be wrapped by phonegap and cordova.

I thought in first place that when the .apk file is created it is compatible regardless what you did to create the app.

Did anyone experienced something like this?

I attach some code to clarify:

HTML

```
<tr class="tappable" id="9" placeid="2" tipologyid="3">
    <td class="home-calendario-td">
        <div class="home-calendario">
            <img src="img/img.png">
            <div class="home-cal-desc">
                <div class="home-cal-title">TITLE</div>
                <div class="home-cal-sub-title">Description</div>
            </div></div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.home-calendario{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:row;
}
.home-calendario img{
    height:32px!important;
    width:32px!important;
    min-width:32px!important;
    margin:5px;
    margin-right:25px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
.home-calendario .home-cal-desc{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    width:100%;
}
.home-calendario .home-cal-desc .home-cal-title{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.home-calendario .home-cal-desc .home-cal-sub-title{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

This is (simplified) one of the part that behave different. There are more, all with flex involved.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you could find different results on different device using PhoneGap.
This happened because every device use the System WebView for rendering your App.
For avoiding this problem you could use [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview), that prevent this issue forcing the device to use the CrossWalk WebView.